# Combining dynamic edittext from listview with a string from database

Tags: android, database, listview, android-edittext, spannablestring

I'm having trouble understanding how to do this function. My application shows a listview to the user with edittext that they will fill out. When they click my confirm button I need take their inputs and then on my next activity combining it with a string stored in my database. The string will contain dynamic text where I need to put the different edit texts in different spots. An example would look something like this....

"This is part of my string where a " (edittext1) " would be in part of the end result. " (Edittext2) " and then more of the string here. etc etc. though I also want to be able to reference previous " (edittext1)  " where I reuse them again. "

I also want to make the edittexts a different color so they stand out from the rest of the text. I was looking into spannablestringbuilders but still having trouble understanding them, mostly how to do the setup above in a dynamic environment. Any explanations or sample code would really help me understand this.

My database is build like this

```
Category_table
_id   Categorykey   categorydesc
1             1          Music
2             0          Movies

Source_table
_id  categorykey     sourcedesc
1         1             Katy Perry
2         1             The Beatles
3         0             Lion King

Title_table
_id     categorykey  source key  titlekey  titledesc   titlestory
1           1            0            1      Kissed A     ""I kissed a(n) "  edittext1 " and I " edittext2 " it. The taste of its "edittext3 " I Kissed a(n) " edittext1 " just to try it. I hope my "edittext4 " don't mind it. It felt so wrong. It felt so right. Don't mean I'm in love tonight. I kissed a(n) "edittext1 " and I " edittext2 " it. I "edittext2 " it."
```

//only putting one there since its so big on last column

```
Userword_table
_id categorykey  sourcekey  titlekey   userword
1        1           0         0        Past Tense Verb
1        1           0         0        Past Tense Verb
1        1           0         0        Noun
1        1           0         0        Noun
```

//a little more to this table but that would be for the above title_table

So I'm using cursors with multi where statements to filter my 4 lvl listview. This next cursor being my current last cursor

```
      public  Cursor getUserWord() 
        {
            return myDataBase.query(USER_WORD_TABLE, new String[] {
                    KEY_ID, 
                    KEY_CATEGORY,
                    KEY_SOURCE, KEY_TITLE, KEY_EDITWORD, KEY_USERWORD 
                    }, 
                    KEY_CATEGORY+ "=" + categories.categoryClick + " AND " + KEY_SOURCE+ "=" 
                    +source.sourceClick + " AND " + KEY_TITLE+ "=" + title.titleClick, 
                    null, null, null, KEY_ID);

        }
```

Let me know if you need more info

Comment: can you provide a design or mock up?